# OpenSCAD navigation through interior of model without zooming in?

Tags: navigation, openscad

I'm creating an OpenSCAD model, and I wanted to inspect the intersection of objects in the interior of the model... how do I 'fly' through the model at normal zoom? Is there a way of doing that?

The only way I can see of moving about is right-click to translate, left-click to rotate, and zoom in and out. Is there a set of keyboard shortcuts that equate to "left", "right", "forward", "backward", "turn left", "turn right", "turn up", "turn down" that would allow flying through the model without zooming in?

I tried zooming in to move into the model, but then using left-click / scroll and right-click / scroll to move about becomes so sensitive that one quickly gets lost.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution would be to make your model transparent. Transparency only works in the f5 render mode. It can be achieved with the `color()` function by specifying an alpha value. You might want to put what you want to make transparent in a `render()` block to avoid having a lot of artifacts an weird render properties like this :

```
color(alpha = 0.5)render()
difference(){
    cylinder(h=8, r=2, center = true);
    rotate([90, 0, 0])
    cylinder(h=4, r=1, center = true);
}
```

The render block makes the equivalent of an f6 render of the subtree so all its intersections a computed for real. This is useful because the f5 render doesn't do that and use rendering tricks instead. It's faster but doesn't work quite well with transparecy.

Answer (score 0):

Fly animation can be achieved by using `special variables` like `$vpt` (for translate) and probably `$vpr`(if you need rotation) and `$t`(which increments from 0 to 1 in steps).

Linear flying is actually very easy:

```
some_translate_multiplier = 200;
$vpt = [$t*some_translate_multiplier, 0, 0];
```

[OpenSCAD User manual](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/OpenSCAD_User_Manual/Other_Language_Features#$vpr,_$vpt,_$vpf_and_$vpd)